# Update date from other table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table called Products_V which has the following columns.

- ProductNumber
- Source
- date

[image]

I want to update date of the table called Product_feed which has the following columns.

- ProductNumber
- source
- date

[image]

I want to update the date of table **Product_feed** by taking the date from table **Product_V** I want to join the tables using columns **ProductNumber and Source** but the problem is values of source is different in both the tables for same ProductNumber.

Like in Table Product_V I have value of Source as SOD

and in Table Product_feed I have value of Source as 'MBUS_MOD' for the same ProductNumber.

The update statement I used:

```
set T1.date =T2.date
from Product_feed T1
join (
    select
      date,
      ProductNumber,
      Source = IIF('MBUS_MOD' ,'SOD' ,NULL)
    from Product_V
) T2
  on T1.Source = T2.Source
  and T1.ProductNumber = T2.ProductNumber
```

Comment: What is your DBMS product? When you have different values in source column product_v and ProductNumber tables, Why do you even want to join the tables on this column?

Comment: From what you've shown, join `on pf.ProductNumber = pv.Productnumber and pf.Source = 'MBUS_' + pv.Source`

Answer (score 0):

If you have unique ProductNumber and if it's not depending on Source (multiple source value for same ProductNumber and in same table) then you don't have to add Source in join statement and below query will work for your scenario

```
update
    Product_feed
set
    date = Products_V.date
from
    Products_V
where
    Product_feed.ProductNumber = Products_V.ProductNumber;
```

Comment: Ankit it depends on the Source that's why i was using the The above Update statement not the one in which join is only on ProductNumber

Comment: That's just a weird implicit join, and does nothing to improve the original query

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you must avoid special words used for the SQL like 'date','Source' etc.

here is a sample code for your Problem, hope it will help.

```
Use master
Go

Declare @ProductsV As Table(
    ProductNumber NVarchar(50) Not Null Default '',
    SourceID NVarchar(50) Not Null Default '',
    VDate date Not Null Default ''
);

Insert Into @ProductsV(ProductNumber,SourceID,VDate)
Select ProductNumber,SourceID,VDate
From(
    Select ProductNumber='MUL-123-0981',SourceID='SOD',VDate='12/15/2021'
    Union All
    Select ProductNumber='MUL-124-0982',SourceID='SOD',VDate='12/16/2021'
    Union All
    Select ProductNumber='MUL-125-0983',SourceID='SOD',VDate='12/17/2021'
    Union All
    Select ProductNumber='MUL-126-0984',SourceID='SOD',VDate='12/18/2021'
    Union All
    Select ProductNumber='MUL-127-0985',SourceID='SOD',VDate='12/19/2021'
    Union All
    Select ProductNumber='MUL-128-0986',SourceID='SOD',VDate='12/20/2021'
) As VData;

Declare @ProductFeed As Table(
    ProductNumber NVarchar(50) Not Null Default '',
    SourceID NVarchar(50) Not Null Default '',
    FDate date Not Null Default ''
);

Insert Into @ProductFeed (ProductNumber,SourceID,FDate)
Select ProductNumber,SourceID,FDate
From(
    Select ProductNumber='MUL-123-0981',SourceID='MBUS_MOD',FDate='11/15/2021'
    Union All
    Select ProductNumber='MUL-124-0982',SourceID='MBUS_MOD',FDate='11/16/2021'
    Union All
    Select ProductNumber='MUL-125-0983',SourceID='MBUS_MOD',FDate='11/17/2021'
    Union All
    Select ProductNumber='MUL-126-0984',SourceID='MBUS_MOD',FDate='11/18/2021'
    Union All
    Select ProductNumber='MUL-127-0985',SourceID='MBUS_MOD',FDate='11/19/2021'
    Union All
    Select ProductNumber='MUL-128-0986',SourceID='MBUS_MOD',FDate='11/20/2021'
) As FData;

Select * From @ProductsV;
Select * From @ProductFeed ;

Update FData Set FData.FDate=VData.VDate
From @ProductsV As VData Join @ProductFeed As FData On (FData.ProductNumber=VData.ProductNumber) And (FData.SourceID='MBUS_MOD') And (VData.SourceID='SOD') And (FData.FDate<>VData.VDate);

Select * From @ProductsV;
Select * From @ProductFeed;
```

Comment: Aside: As explained in Rule 3 for [Rules for Regular Identifiers](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/database-identifiers?view=sql-server-ver15#rules-for-regular-identifiers): "The identifier must not be a Transact-SQL reserved word. SQL Server reserves both the uppercase and lowercase versions of reserved words. When identifiers are used in Transact-SQL statements, the identifiers that do not comply with these rules must be delimited by double quotation marks or brackets." The OP can tease the database with `select [Update] from [Where] where [Date] > [From];`